# Split the String and get different output

Tags: c#, split

I have 2 different strings need to split them get the output as I needed. Trying different solutions didnt work for me and blocked

**Input**

```
"12.2 - Chemicals, products and including,14.0 - Plastic products ,17.2 - Metal Products ,19.1 - and optical equipment (excluding and other electronic components; semiconductors; bare printed circuit boards; opti, watches)"
```

**OutPut**

```
"12.2, 14.0, 17.2, 19.1"
```

The other case. [UpDated as per new codes]

**Input**

```
"MD 0102.2.3 - Test 123 ,MD 0102.2.5 - Test Hello ,MD 1101.2 - Dialysis and blood treatment, MDM 123 - Test, MDM 12.32.0 - Test 12"
```

**Output**

```
"MD 0102.2.3, MD 0102.2.5,MD 1101.2,MDM 123,MDM 12.32.0"
```

didn't understand which logic I need to find it.

Comment: What are the exact rules? are these 2 examples the extent of the variations?

Comment: First string need to extract only Numbers, Second string with First value DM or RD with Number

Comment: Is there ever a TR or BX, or HH, are these the ***only*** 2 variations of input?

Comment: only 2 variations , both are different strings and need different output

Comment: Do I get it right: you want to split at comma, and then strip everything after and including the first minus sign from each of the parts?

Comment: [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0) is your friend.

Comment: split the action up. 1) split by ",", 2) split each element by '-' and 3) take the first of those, 4) trim those, and 5) join by ", "

Comment: @JHBonarius not quite. Was also my first idea, but there are additional commas like the one after "Chemicals" which prevent this approach.

Comment: Well, looking more at this, it's just bad data. If comma is a separator using in the individual strings, it should not be used as a separator between the strings. IMHO you're polishing a turd (no offense).

Comment: `string[] items = Regex.Matches(source, @"[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: Hi @Dmitry .. Need some suggestions.. we have seen some different codes in production which our code is not working, I tired to modify the existing code to work but didn't work for me.. Max possible code as below .. "MD 0102.2.3 - Test 123 ,MD 0102.2.5 - Test Hello ,MD 1101.2 - Dialysis and blood treatment, MDM 123 - Test, MDM 12.32.0 - Test 12" we need data till " - " .. Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve both tasks with a help of *regular expressions* and *Linq*. The only difference is in the patterns ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tYDe0R)):

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string input = "12.2 - Chemicals, products and including,14.0 - Plastic products ,17.2 - Metal Products ,19.1 - and optical equipment ...";

  string pattern = @"[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]";

  string[] result = Regex
    .Matches(input, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Note, it is `pattern` which differ

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string input = "DM 0405 - trtststodfm, fhreuu ,RD 3756 - yeyerffydydyd";

  string pattern = @"[A-Z]{2}\s[0-9]{4}";
  
  string[] result = Regex
    .Matches(input, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Patterns explained:

```
  [A-Z]{2}\s[0-9]{4}

     [A-Z]{2} - 2 capital English letters in A..Z range
          \s  - white space
     [0-9]{4} - 4 digits in 0..9 range

  [0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]

     [0-9]{1,2} - from 1 up to 2 digits in 0..9 range
             \. - dot .
          [0-9] - digit in 0..9 range
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitry .. Need some suggestions.. we have seen some different codes in production which our code is not working, I tired to modify the existing code to work but didn't work for me.. Max possible code as below ..  "MD 0102.2.3 - Test 123 ,MD 0102.2.5 - Test Hello ,MD 1101.2 - Dialysis and blood treatment, MDM 123 - Test, MDM 12.32.0 - Test 12" we need data till " - " .. Thanks In Advance

Comment: @Satti: if you have `####.#.#`, `##.##.#`, `####.#` and alike patterns, you can try `[0-9]{2,4}\.[0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9])?` pattern

Answer (score 1):

If the input is always in the combination of {id}-{item},{id}-{item}.
I would split the string on the ',' character. After you've done that it would be quick if you search through the collection with [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) and [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0).

But you would need to know in what formats the ID of the item can have.
if it is like

> 2.2, 14.0, 17.2, 19.1

and does not change. Then a simple [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0) like beneath suffices, which you can use in your Linq query.

```
new Regex(@"(\d*\.\d*)")
```

Comment: Please, escape `.` as `\.` in the regular expression pattern, unescaped since dot ('.') means *any symbol*

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex: `((\w{2} \d{4})|\d+\.\d+)(?=( - ))`

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0pTqFQ

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input1 = "12.2 - Chemicals, products and including,14.0 - Plastic products ,17.2 - Metal Products ,19.1 - and optical equipment (excluding and other electronic components; semiconductors; bare printed circuit boards; opti, watches)";
        string input2 = "DM 0405 - trtststodfm, fhreuu ,RD 3756 - yeyerffydydyd";
        
        var regex1 = new Regex(@"((\w{2} \d{4})|\d+\.\d+)(?=( - ))");
        var matches1 = regex1.Matches(input1);
        var matches2 = regex1.Matches(input2);
        
        PrintMatches(matches1);
        PrintMatches(matches2);
    }
    
    private static void PrintMatches(MatchCollection matches)
    {
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
    }
}
```